# Converting string date to ODBC canonical date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working with SQL 2008 R2. We have a third party software that is passing a string to a stored proc. The string is a date in the format of:

```
2015-05-27 11:59pm
```

I have no access to this formatting and cannot change it. I need to convert this string to the proper format for SQL to use properly in my Stored Proc. The problem with it as is, is that it is ignoring the hours and min part of the date.

example of what i am trying to accomplish:

```
2015-05-27 11:59pm = 2015-05-27 23:59:00.000
2015-05-27 01:15am = 2015-05-27 01:15:00.000
```

I've tried:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),'2015-05-27 11:59pm',121)
```

which converts it to :

```
2015-05-27 11:59PM
```

I've tried
    CAST('2015-05-27 11:59pm' AS DATETIME)
which converts it to:

```
2015-05-27 00:00:00.000
```

Is there a way I can convert the string and keep the hour and minute portion?

Comment: can't really test for this in sqlfiddle beccause it automatically saves without am/pm (gives 24 hour notation automatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-05-27 11:59pm', 121)
```

Comment: This solution also works, The main problem was using varchar instead of datetime. but i think 121 is preferable over 0 as it is slightly more precise although I don't think I'll need it.

Comment: @Gene, actually he was the first :) This is like a stack. First goes to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

This expression:

```
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), '2015-05-27 11:59pm', 121)
```

is not correct.  It takes the date string, converts it to a date/time using internal settings.  Then it converts that date/time to a string.  Try converting the value to a `datetime` directly:

```
 convert(datetime, @param, 121)
```

However, I think it would be better for your stored procedure to just take a date time parameter rather than a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-05-27 11:59pm', 0)
```

Output:

```
2015-05-27 23:59:00.000
```

Comment: isn't 0 the way to actually get AM and PM? according to http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp, I think you need 121

Comment: This solution works, replacing the VARCHAR with datetime solved the problem.